# Firebase Emulator Fails To Start

Tags: firebase, firebase-tools

I have been learning to use Google Firebase recently and have a project set up in the Console, Functions, Auth, Storage all set up with the corresponding files all configured, firebasesrc, firebase.json, rules, indexes, functions folder, etc.

Everything was going fine until I shut down VS Code. I reopened it and attempted to restart the emulator (along with auth, store & functions and import some test data) using

`firebase emulators:start --only firestore,auth,functions --import test-data`

However I am faced with the following error in the Terminal...

```
i  emulators: Shutting down emulators.

Error: No emulators to start, run firebase init emulators to get started.
```

My question is do I have to initialise everything every time I shut down and reopen using.. `firebase init` or `firebase init emulators`?

My Java window is closed down by the way.

Comment: Are they working fine after init? If yes, does this problem occur every time after VS shut down?

Comment: I haven't completed the run of init yet as it's running me through the same init questions (which files to use for rules, indexes, etc), however asking me to overwrite some or take the default, which I don't want to do. I just wanted to see if init in necessary everytime you reopen VS

Comment: No it's not necessary, I think that there is some issue with caching of firebase settings. I would try to init it again and see what happens, if possible ofc.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I'll start a full init of the project and hopefully that sorts it

Comment: Didn't fix the issue. Still faced with the same error message

Answer (score 0):

I ended up running

```
npm run local-dev
```

which in my firebase.json was set to

```
"local-dev": "firebase emulators:start --only firestore,auth,functions --import test-data",
```

which seems to have sorted the issue.